# How to create enum in swift with only digital as accepable string

Tags: swift, enums

I want to create an enum in swift with only digital (i.e. "0" .. "9" as accepable values.

```
public enum Digit: String {
    case "1"
    case "2"
    case "3"
    case "4"
    case "5"
    case "6"
    case "7"
    case "8"
    case "9"
    case "0"
}
```

But I get compile error saying `Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'` .
I try doing

```
public enum Digit: String {
        case 1

}
```

but that does not work either.

Comment: `case one = "1", two = "2"`,  and so on

Comment: You can't name your cases starting with numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enum cases can't be raw type ie., `String` ("1") or `Int` (1). You need to add cases as follows.

```
public enum Digit: String {
    case one = "1"
    case two = "2"
    //...
}
```

Although you could add a custom `init` for `Int` as follows.

```
public enum Digit: String {
    //...
    init?(rawValue: Int) {
        switch rawValue {
        case 1: self == one
        case 2: self == two
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think OP wants to change the rawValue type to `Int`. His main issue was trying to assign a `String` and/or `Int` to the case name.

Comment: Yes. I want to enum to be String type.